# Инициализация bean в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-core

Я читаю документацию на официальном сайте Spring, на данный момент изучаю основы Spring core и мне уже немного известно про Spring MVC и меня беспокоит следующий вопрос, ответа на который я пока что не нашел, возможно из-за какого-то своего недопонимания.
В официальной документации в примерах использования бинов пишется примерно следующее:

**Инициализация через XML!**

```
<!—-applCntx.xml—->
<bean id=“...” class=“...”/>
```

Далее в методе main мы инициализируем наш контейнер бинов

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(“applCntx.xml”);
context.getBean(...)
```

Это все понятно и просто, но не понятно следующее:
На сколько мне известно, Spring MVC работает на основе сервлетов и следовательно метод `main` не нужен, точнее метод `main` находится «под капотом» Tomcat.
Как тогда происходит инициализации контейнера? Внутри самого Tomcat? К примеру мне нужно внедрение зависимости в контроллере:

```
@Controller
public class PetController{
//вот сюда надо внедрить зависимость
  public TestClass clazz;

  @GetMapping(“/“)
  public String methodTest(DtoObj obj){
    return clazz.getSomeThing(obj);
  }
}
```

Как мне сделать это посредством именно XML конфигурации, без использования аннотаций (я понимаю, что сейчас пользуются практически только Java конфигурацией Spring без XML, но это же основы и мне важно понимать это)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала небольшая вводная по war-приложениям (сервлеты их часть). Эти приложения поднимаются не командой `java -jar твойДжаник.jar` а специальной штукой, которая называется контейнер сервлетов. Это и есть тот самый Tomcat, Jetty/Netty или Undertow. Согласно спецификации сервлетов, контейнер сервлетов просканирует твоё приложение на предмет наличия классов, реализующих интерфейс [javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). Если таковые есть, то он создаст их и вызовет соответствующий метод в начале запуска приложения. Очень грубо можем назвать это аналогом метода `main` для war-приложения.

В spring имеется класс, реализующий данный интерфейс [org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.html), который в свою очередь сканирует наличие классов, реализующих интерфейс [org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html), и запускает уже у них соответствующий метод.

Обратившись к [официальной документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-servlet) можно увидеть пример того, как инициализировать Spring внутри приложения

```java
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

        // Load Spring web application configuration
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Create and register the DispatcherServlet
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("app", servlet);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/app/*");
    }
}
```

Ну или в случаем xml-конфигурации та же [документация](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-container-config) говорит следующее

```java
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

где `/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml` - твоя xml-конфигурация для spring.

**Т.е. контейнер сервлетов инициализирует приложение, которое в свою очередь внутри себя поднимает Spring.**

Как объявить `@Controller` средствами xml?

Дело в том, что никак. Из-за сложности связывания методов и URI-путей, которые они обслуживают xml был бы переусложнён. Т.е. нет аналогий `@GetMapping` и ему подобных в xml-конфигурации.

Comment: спасибо огромное! Собственно, надо бы сначала полностью дочитать документацию)